# R is only displaying every other horizontal axis label

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

It appears that R is only displaying every other horizontal axis label in my plot (only a tic mark is displayed on every other x-axis and no text is included). How do I allow it to display every single label, and not every other one?

[Plot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkm7L.png)

My code:

```
par(mar=c(13, 8, 4.1, 2.1))        
boxplot(MS, names=MSN, las=2, ylim=c(472,528))       
abline(h=504, col="blue")       
axis(2, at = c(501.5), las=2, label=c("50th %ile"), col.axis="red")
abline(h=c(472,475,480,485,490,495,500,505,510,515,520,525,528),
  col="gray", lty=2,lwd=1)
abline(v=c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39,41,43,45,47,49,51,53,55,57,59,61,63,65,67,69.71,73,75,77,79,81,83,85,87,89,91,93,95,97,99,101,103,105,107,109,111,113,115,117,119,121,123,125,127,129,131,133,135,137,139,141,143),
  col="gray", lty=2,lwd=0.25)
```

Comment: Most likely too large x-axis tic font. Can't tell for sure because no data posted.

Comment: What code would you recommend using to decrease the x-axis tic font? Also, is there a way to spread out the x-axis to touch the ends of the box (and thereby reduce the margins of the plot on the x-axis)? There is a lot of space with no text on either end of the x-axis in the plotted area.

Comment: Try `cex.axis=0.5` or lower for the font. Use `axis` if you want to control axes separately. Spread out within the plot area? Not sure. Possibly an artifact of spacings within the plot. I would have to test that on a similar dataset.

Comment: Use `axis(gap.axis = 0)` to display all tick labels regardless of whether they "fit". See `?axis` for documentation.

Comment: `?par` explains how to control margins and other graphical parameters not available as arguments to the various plotting functions.

Comment: ```cex.axis=0.75``` worked! However, this changed both the x and y axis text size. How do I only change the x-axis text size while keeping the Y-axis text size the same?

Comment: @John By using `axis` for x and y. See `?axis`. Btw, if you use `frame=F` within box plot you won't see the gaps on the left and right side anymore.

Comment: When I use axis() to only change the x-axis font size, it then inserts numbers into the x-axis on top of my text, rather than changing the size of my text. I'm guessing it's thinking I want the numerical values on the x-axis, rather than the text of the names() in the boxplot function. What code should I insert to change the font size of the names() in boxplot()? -My apologies, I'm still a beginner at using R.

Comment: Also, it looks like using frame=F will eliminate the lines of the gaps on the left and right of the boxplot, but it won't reduce this space and fill it with more x-axis labels. It will just keep it as gaps without the line. How do I actually fill this gap space with more x-axis labels?

Comment: Please always post questions with data, that helps avoid lengthy discussions like this... As for the axis, of course when you add new axes you have to disable the ones generated by boxplot, e.g. `axes=F`.